# Refactoring JS Code

Tags: javascript

I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of a link/article that would help me understand refactoring JavaScript. I tend to use alot of nested if/else statements and want to learn to clean up code.

Any explanation on how you would refactor the code below would help tremendously. Thanks in advance!

```
var yourself = {
    fibonacci : function(n) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n === 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return this.fibonacci(n - 1) +
            this.fibonacci(n - 2);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking - in what way do you want it to be improved?  how are you using fibonacci?  only suggestion I can make is to remove the 'this' reference and simply call fibonacci

Comment: Sadly this is one of the cons of javascript. I dont know any stable way to do this, you can try with typescript next time

Comment: The only question I have is whether this is Too Broad or Opinion Based.

Comment: For this specific example, I would look into using the mathematical formula rather than recursion if you're looking to save memory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is on topic on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: FYI, improving a recursive Fibonacci generator is the given example for memoization in _JavaScript: The Good Parts_.

Comment: It was more of a question about refactoring in general than the specific function so I apologize for being so vague. I'll be sure to read that link @Wintermute

Comment: @Mathletics I just bought that book last week but haven't had a chance to get past the 1st chapter yet. This weekend I'll be buried in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, refactoring is mostly a matter of style and readability. First I noticed that the first two if branches look almost identical. Surely I can combine them somehow? So I did this:

```
var yourself = { 
  fibonacci : function(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
      return n;
    }   
    else {
      return this.fibonacci(n - 1) + this.fibonacci(n - 2); 
    }   
  }
};
```

Not too shabby. What else can we do? The if branches don't actually need braces. This is actually a dangerous habit, but I'll explain later.

```
var yourself = { 
  fibonacci : function(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1)
      return n;
    else
      return this.fibonacci(n - 1) + this.fibonacci(n - 2); 
  }
};
```

Now let's get exotic and use the ternary operator!

```
var yourself = { 
  fibonacci : function(n) {
    return (n === 0 || n === 1) ? n : this.fibonacci(n - 1) + this.fibonacci(n - 2); 
  }
};
```

Wow that's pretty ugly isn't it? Hard to read, all on one line, but so concise.

That's why it's important to re-evaluate every time you refactor.

Ask yourself: Is this easy to understand? Can I tell at a glance just what's going on? In that last example we lost a lot of indentation which is helpful for figuring out the general structure and flow of your code. We lost some helpful visual information by preferring concise code.

I wouldn't go with the second refactor attempt either. Removing those braces is a bad idea because it only works with one-line branches. If you go back later and add a second line, but you forget to add the braces back then you'll get a very cryptic error when you try to run your code.

I think your original code is actually great. It's concise and clear, and easy to understand. It literally spells out the definition of the fibonacci function: "If it's 0 or 1, return that. Otherwise, recursively compute the result."

Refactoring comes from experience, from twiddling with the code until it looks right, and from constantly asking yourself whether this is really an improvement. Value clarity above all, then performance, and be wary of conciseness.

For some extra reading, the AirBnB style guide is well regarded:
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: This is precisely the kind of response I was hoping for! Thanks Michael!

Comment: Glad to help, and thanks for my first upvote ever!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a cache.

```js
var yourself = {
    cache : {},
    fibonacci : function(n) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n === 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(this.cache[n]){
          console.log('cache return');
          return this.cache[n];
        }
        else {
            this.cache[n] = this.fibonacci(n - 1) +
            this.fibonacci(n - 2);
            return this.cache[n];
        }
    }
};
console.log(
yourself.fibonacci(12)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think I would note that a return is a return (exit path) from the code.  The else should be unnecessary.

```
var yourself = {
  fibonacci : function(n) {
    // Return quickly for the trivial cases
    if (n < 2) { return n; }
    // ...otherwise calculate it recursively
    return this.fibonacci(n - 1) + this.fibonacci(n - 2);
  }
};
```

A good book is [Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/Default.aspx).  I can't tell you if the latest revision includes JavaScript yet it goes into great detail about cleaning up code and the benefit of good source code formatting.

Others will strongly disagree to the fact that I didn't add a hard return after the if statement and yet I find this short test-and-exit code style to make for faster reading.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll be sure to check that out after I learn the language a little more.